# A problem about Frattini subgroup of a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, frattini-subgroup

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Does that imply, that 
$\Phi(H)\le \Phi(G)$? If not, then what properties $G$ must have for it to be true.

$\Phi$ stands for Fattini subgroup .

Comment: It is not true in general.  For instance, a finite simple group $G$ satisfies $\Phi(G)=1$ (why?); but for any Sylow $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$ which is not elementary abelian, $\Phi(H)\neq 1$.  If $H$ is normal, the answer is affirmative in general (at least when $G$ is finite).

Comment: I think *G* has to be  non-abelian finite p-group but i'm not sure it is enough or right

Comment: I think yes, every subgroup is subnormal, and we can use induction together with the positive answer for normal subgroups.  Or directly use the fact that $\Phi(G)=G'G^p$.  Try to think about more general classes.